# Rails db migrate generate migrate file

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When working on a project, I keep track of all the changes I make to a database in a notepad file. Then, later, I manually write all the changes in rails' db migration file.

But it should be possible to compare the schema of a backup of my database, with the new version of my database, and automatically detect the differences. And generate the rails db migration file automatically.

Is there a tool that can compare two database schema's and automatically generate rails' db migration files?

Comment: Don't change the schema file manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, there's no tool that will do it automatically, however, you can get most of the way there just using `rake db:schema:dump` with source control.

Create a new Rails project and do the following:

1. Update database.yml to connect to your first database.
2. Use `rake db:schema:dump` to populate `schema.rb` and commit `schema.rb` to git.
3. Update database.yml to connect to your second database and again run `rake db:schema:dump`
4. Use `git diff` on `schema.rb` to compare the changes. This can easily be mapped to a migration.

The benefit of using source control is that you can then test the migration by comparing `schema.rb` after the migration runs to the schema dump of the second database.